# React web-app separation with shared redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

My goal is to be able to deploy separately parts of my web application.

I want to break my webapp into parts with a shared redux state among them.
I have no idea how to start.

Is it possible?
What is the best practice to share a state?
Is it possible to route from one app to the other?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to share the Redux state to another webapp directly, but you could either use a database to store the last state before redirecting linked to the user and initialize it as initial state when creating the reducers. E.g.:

```
const initialState = getStateFromDB(userid);

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW_LOADING':
      return {...state, loading: true}
    case 'HIDE_LOADING':
      return {...state, loading: false}
    case 'SHOW_MESSAGE':
      return {...state, showingMessage: true, message: action.message}
    case 'HIDE_MESSAGE':
      return {...state, showingMessage: false, message: ''}
    //whatever actions
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If by separation, you mean different react instances in general, then...

#### Phase 1 (Database)

You would have to rely on a database and connecting to it.

#### Phase 2 (More Database w/ Sessions)

If there are use specific options, then you would have to have session management within the database/middleware.

#### Phase 3 (Sockets)

If the data needs to be in sync at all times, then you can add middleware with web sockets.

...at least, that's how I'd end up going about it.